# Association has_many/belongs_to with an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, foreign-keys, associations

I have a `SkillList` model. Database in this table contains a list of all possible skills.

There is a `UserSkill` model. An array is stored in database, which lists the id of user's skills.

*My models:*

```
class SkillList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_skill, foreign_key: 'skill_id'
end


class UserSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skill_lists
  belongs_to :user
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_skill, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The `user_skills` table has a `skill_id` field, it stores my array.

I get a skills record for user using association - `user.user_skill`

Is it possible to use an association to get all skill records from an array of user skills?

For example: `user.user_skill.skill_lists`

[image: Table structure]

Comment: I don't get how you can store an array, does the `belongs_to :user_skill, foreign_key: 'skill_id'` association work? active_record expects an interger column for `belongs_to ...` to work, not an array.

Comment: Anyway, if you still want to have an array, just create a method on UserSkill: `def skills SkillList.where(id: skill_id) end`

Comment: @arieljuod Association doesn't work. Foreign key for an example. It turns out that there is no way to work with arrays without an N + 1 problem?

Comment: I guess you can use an array withouth N+1 queries, but not with standard activercord association, you'll have to implement that yourself. I wouldn't use an array to store those ids, moving out from rails' conventions can be done but it requires extra work with little benefit.

Comment: I suggest adding a join model/table between `UserSkill` and `SkillList` named `UserSkillList`. Getting rid of the array field, allowing the Rails associations to function correctly.